# Crystal Report Viewer is showing blank page

Tags: asp.net, crystal-reports, iis-8

The Crystal Report Viewer is showing blank page. I have checked all the possible causes but the http://domain.com/aspnet_client/system_web/4_6_1069/crystalreportviewers13/js/crviewer/crv.js is not found.

I have set virtual directory as aspnet_client to the website root directory.

Please help...

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem and installing support pack 19 from this [link](https://wiki.scn.sap.com/wiki/display/BOBJ/Crystal+Reports%2C+Developer+for+Visual+Studio+Downloads) resolved this.

Answer (score 0):

In some server it is looking for a folder in website directory called 4_6_1069.
Just had to copy the earlier version Cr files to that folder and it worked nicely.

Answer (score 0):

i also faced same problem and found by inspecting with firebug that there is a missing file name crv.js. added the that file manually into my crystal report viewer page.

```
<script src="/crystalreportviewers13/js/crviewer/crv.js"></script>
```